# NSInvocation has retainArguments, why is there no releaseArguments?

Tags: objective-c, nsinvocation

NSInvocation has retainArguments to retain the arguments.  Why is there no releaseArguments? Why will the retained arguments be freed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `-retainArguments` is called, the instance of `NSInvocation` holds a strong reference to each of the arguments. Like any strong reference, the arguments are retained until the instance of `NSInvocation` is released.